# How can I see which Slack channel(s) myself and another Slack user are both a member of?

Tags: slack

I wonder how I can see which Slack channel(s) myself and another Slack user in my workspace are both a member of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no way to see which Slack channel(s) myself and another Slack user in my workspace are both a member of, unless perhaps resorting to the Slack API.